# how to get list of all attribute and method from an JSObjects in dart

Tags: webview, dart

Let’s say you want to use the following JavaScript code:

```
var Point = function(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.distanceFrom = function(otherPoint) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(otherPoint.x - this.x, 2) +
    Math.pow(otherPoint.y - this.y, 2));
  };
};
```

In your Dart code, use the indexing operator ([]) to get and set properties:

```
var p1 = new JsObject(context['Point'], [5, 1]);
print(p1['x']); // Prints 5.
```

BUT how can I get a list of all keys/methods/vars

like

```
p1['attributes'] or p1['keys']
```

that would return

```
[a,b]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
js.context['Object'].callMethod('keys', [p1]);
```